# Maximal Complexity of Other Way Mazes

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Here's an other-way maze.

[image: Other Way Maze]

Some code is at [Other Way Maze](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/990814).

Out of 625 possible positions, this maze seems to require 145 moves to solve. Is that the most possible for a 5x5 grid?

What other incredibly complicated mazes can be packed into a tiny space?

Comment: Interesting. The first instruction says "the center" (center square, I guess?) but the second one refers to an arrow under *either* coin - aren't they on the same square at the start?